# Codeigniter 2.2.6 XML-RPC Error

Tags: php, xml, codeigniter

Am using codeigniter 2.2.6 and i got error `The XML data received was either invalid or not in the correct form for XML-RPC.  Turn on debugging to examine the XML data`. I cant fix this error, help me please.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What XML are you receiving?  Have you ran it through a validator to check it is correct?

Comment: i have received no data but its shows the above error only

Comment: If you've not received any data and are trying to process it as XML then you would get this message.  A blank string or null can't be processed as XML.  You'll need to look into why you aren't getting any data; that's where the real issue lies.  What are you doing in order to try to get the XML, and are there any errors generated there?